# Cannot assign "'Album object (6)'": "Music.album_id" must be a "Album" instance

Tags: python, django

I spend a lot of time in google and find a few solutions for my problem
but none of them works :((

models :

```
    class Album(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
         author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
         picture_address = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
         creation_year = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
         rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    class Music(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
         cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_destination)
         album_id = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and here is form :

```
class music_create_form(forms.ModelForm):
album_options = [('', '')]
for album in models.Album.objects.all():
    album_options.append((album,album.name))

name = forms.CharField(required=True
                       , widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "normal_padding form-control"}))
cover = forms.FileField(required=True
                        , widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': "normal_padding", 'accept': "image/jpeg"}))
album_id = forms.Field(required=True
                       ,
                       widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "normal_padding form-control"}, choices=album_options))

class Meta:
    model = models.Music
    fields = [
        'name', 'cover', 'album_id'
    ]
```

and here is view :

```
def create_music(request):

    form = forms.music_create_form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    context = {'form': form}
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form)
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.save()
            context['action_done'] = True

    return render(request, 'music/create_music.html', context)
```

when i try to add new  model with that form , i got the error at this line : " if form.is_valid() "

**`Cannot assign “'Album object (6)'”: “Music.album_id” must be a “Album” instance`**

This is my form in template :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <h5 class="normal_padding">Music Name:</h5>
                    {{ form.name }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <h5 class="normal_padding">Music Cover:</h5>
                    {{ form.cover }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <h5 class="normal_padding">Album:</h5>
                    {{ form.album_id }}
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save data</button>

            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: have you tried same by using Albums.objects.all() as choices in form field album_id..

Comment: @py-D yeah , this will get error like this : "  'Album' object is not iterable "

Comment: try by useing queryset=Albums.objects.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `forms.Field`. In this case, you should use a `ModelChoiceField`, that will take care of getting the choices for you.

```
class MusicCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True
                           , widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "normal_padding form-control"}))

    cover = forms.FileField(required=True
                            , widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': "normal_padding", 'accept': "image/jpeg"}))

    album_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Album.objects.all(),
                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "normal_padding form-control"}))
```

As an aside, it would be better to rename your `ForeignKey` and form field to `album`. That way `music.album` is the related album and `music.album_id` is it's id. At the moment, `music.album_id` is the album and `music.album_id_id` is the id.

Comment: Thanks , this will solve the error , but form is not valid so i cant save data

Comment: Why is the form not valid? What are the form errors?

Comment: it will give me this error <ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field cannot be null.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: which means 'name' field is null , but im giving value to this

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that would explain that. What is the value of `request.POST` in your view? What does your template look like?

Comment: found the problem ,i made a mistake in clean_name method in forms class  , when i solve that , it works like a charm . Thank you very much